# Наперсница - при чем тут грудь?

Tags: этимология

Наперсница - близкая подруга, доверенное лицо. Как я понимаю, слово произошло от "перси" - то есть, грудь. Но какая связь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы говорим: сердечный друг. Здесь, вероятно, тот же самый смысл.

Answer (score 4):

Наперсница - очень близкая подруга, с которой вы как бы вскормены одной грудью. Еще одно значение слова "наперсник" - воспитатель, то есть вскормивший (вос-питавший)

Answer (score 2):

Можно прижаться к груди, поплакаться, по секрету рассказать...

Answer (score 1):

Это слово, имеющее значение "друг и доверенное лицо", было образовано в старославянском по методу кальки с греческого epistethios: epi – "на", steth(os) – "пьрс(ь)", ios – "ьник".

Еще есть вид одежды, который тоже так назывался, нагрудник особой формы и назначения.

Answer (score 0):

Наперсник
Это слово, имеющее значение "друг и доверенное лицо", было образовано в старославянском по методу кальки с греческого epistethios: epi – "на", steth(os) – "пьрс(ь)", ios – "ьник".
Share on vk Share on facebook Share on livejournal Share on twitter Share on favorites Share on email | More Sharing ServicesЕщё
Можно предложить и такой вариант - вместе занимались рукоделием, вышивали и пользовались 
одним НАПЁРСТКОМ.Буква Т со временем выпала.